# Textarea value="Value" not working onload, but will onblur

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

[Here is my jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JkNG6/), the textarea shows no value onload, but will onblur, does textarea not accept the value attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Here is the solution :)](http://jsfiddle.net/mfkuv/)**

Because you are using a `textarea`, its value comes in between its tag name:

`<textarea class="jsf" name="msg" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Write here!';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Write here!') this.value='';">Write here!</textarea>`

Comment: Thanks, but how do I add this to `{textarea onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Skriv her';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Skriv her') this.value='';"}`? there isn't an option to close the tags in this smarty system, I tried with `{/textarea}` but it broke it.

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: sorry but i have no idea about smarty because i have not used it yet :(

Comment: no worries, I'll figure it out :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.